# Highcharts Trying to Hide/Show series

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, coffeescript

I have an Angular webapp that I am using Highcarts with to display data. The chart is configured like the following initially. In a controller (I use Coffeescript)

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
        options:
            chart:
                type: 'spline'
                plotBackgroundColor: null
            legend:
                enabled: true
            title:
                text: ''
            subtitle:
                text: ''
            exporting:
                url: $config.exportAddress
                width: 1000
        series: [{
             name: ''
            data: [
            ]
            },{
            name: ''
            data: [
            ]
            }]
        loading: false
        xAxis:
            categories: [
            ]
            title:
                text: ''
        yAxis:
            title:
                text: ''
        useHighStocks: false
        size:
            height: 500
    }
```

And displayed in the HTML using

```
<div class="panel-body" id="report-display normalchart" ng-if="!productMonthlyChart">
   <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig"></highchart>
</div>
```

Using a function I push data into the chart like the following

```
$scope.chartConfig.series.length = 0
        # Set title and chart time and and name
        $scope.chartConfig.xAxis.categories = ['Build Overview']
        $scope.chartConfig.options.chart.type = 'column'
        $scope.graphName = 'Column Chart'
        $scope.chartConfig.series.push({name: 'Admitted', data: [$scope.fullBuildTotals.admitted]})
        $scope.chartConfig.series.push({name: 'Deprecated', data: [$scope.fullBuildTotals.deprecated]})
```

I need to be able to show and hide series on the chart however I cannot get it to work using the following show or hide code

```
$scope.chartConfig.series[0].show()
$scope.chartConfig.series[0].hide()
```

I get the following error in the console

***TypeError: $scope.chartConfig.series[0].hide is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.showCurrentBuildReportChartData***

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening? I also came across code where you select the DIV the Chart is contained in call a highcharts() function on it to get the chart but that did not work either.

Comment: it didnt work because you were trying to call show/hide method on chart config object. You need to get actual instance of chart and then call those methods. With jQuery you can get it with $(chartContainer).highcharts()

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, not sure why series[0].show() and .hide() didn't work but an alternative is to directly do what those functions do anyway.

```
$scope.chartConfig.series[0].visible = true
$scope.chartConfig.series[0].visible = false
```

The above code works perfectly.